# How to create a web django system with a dynamic apps?

Tags: html, css, django

I need o create a django system with a dynamic apps. In another words: when the client buy the system, we will to enable whats apps they will use according to the contracted package and it needs to be intuitive because the sells time need to enable the apps without needing the dev.

Can you guys already make something like this ?? I have no idea how start.